# Client Digest Authentication with POCO

Tags: c++, http, poco-libraries, digest-authentication

I'm using POCO for some service client. Client should login with digest authentication.

[POCO documentation claims that digest authentication is supported](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPCredentials.html).

> This is a utility class for working with HTTP authentication (basic or
>   **digest**) in HTTPRequest objects.

Here is full source of test (gtest) showing that there is some problem:

```
#include "UnitTest.h"
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/StreamCopier.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPCredentials.h>

using namespace Poco::Net;

TEST(PocoDigestAuthTest, HttpBibOrgTest) {
    HTTPClientSession session;
    session.setHost("httpbin.org");

    HTTPRequest request(
        "GET", 
        // "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd", // basic
        "http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd",  // digest
        HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    session.sendRequest(request);

    HTTPResponse response;
    std::istream& firstResponseStream = session.receiveResponse(response);
    std::stringstream firstStrStream;
    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(firstResponseStream, firstStrStream);

    ASSERT_EQ(HTTPResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatus());

    HTTPCredentials creds("user", "passwd");
    creds.authenticate(request, response);
    session.sendRequest(request);

    std::istream& bodyStream = session.receiveResponse(response);
    EXPECT_NE(HTTPResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatus());
    EXPECT_EQ(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK, response.getStatus());

    std::stringstream strStream;
    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(bodyStream, strStream);
    EXPECT_NE("", strStream.str());
}
```

This test fails where status HTTP_OK is expected, I'm getting 401 (HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) so earlier check also fails.

If I change uri to site with basic authentication, everything works as expected (test passes).

What I'm doing wrong? Or is it a bug in POCO? Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: Probably a bug. After some labor to figure out what's going on, I filed [a  github issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/753)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing and mind bending it turned out that the issue has nothing to do with digest authentication. You'll also need to send the cookie (fake=fake_value) set by the httpbin.org server. [Here](https://gist.github.com/obiltschnig/348a1cddc3d0b823e8ee) is a modified version of your sample that works. Note the additional call to setCookies(). Also, when creating the HTTPRequest, only the path needs to be supplied, not the entire URI.

Comment: Thanks this works. My question is should I handle cookies somehow during lifetime of http session? Or can I simply use this cookies only during digest authentication?

Comment: This behavior is specific to httpbin.org. Whether you'll have to handle cookies depends on the web service you're using. Most web services don't use cookies. If you need to handle cookies, there's a bit of work involved, as you'll need to keep track of which cookies belong to which server (and paths), as well as cookie life times.

Comment: Is there some page with instruction/example how to do it with Poco? I'm not familiar with this library and I have only basic knowledge about http protocol?

Comment: There's nothing poco specific in the said management. The response will have cookies that server sends to you. If it expects to receive them back in the subsequent request(s) (as httpbin apparently does), you'll have to provide them. Keeping track of cookies and their lifetimes for particular servers and paths is yours to design; cookies themselves will contain all the information you need to know (expiration, domain, path etc). STL containers (std::map in particular) will definitely be of help to keep track.